# How do i check for Collision in a tile based game for android?

Tags: java, android

How can i check for Collision in a tile based game? I have looked at the samples android SDK has, but i can not understand them because I'm new to Android programming.

This is my Map and tile classes which my hero takes in so i can move him around in the world

```
 class Map{
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0; 
    int tileSize = 30;

    int [][]map= {
            //0 = empty tile
            //1 = wall
            //2 = player
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            };



    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();;

    public Map(){
        loadArray();
    }

    public void loadArray(){

        for(int xTiles = 0; xTiles< map.length; xTiles++ ){
            for(int yTiles = 0; yTiles< map[xTiles].length; yTiles++){
                if(map[xTiles][yTiles]==1){//Wall
                tiles.add(new Tile(X, Y, tileSize, map[xTiles][yTiles]));
                tiles.get(tiles.size()-1).setColor(Color.GRAY);
                tiles.get(tiles.size()-1).walkable = false;
                X+=tileSize;
                }else if(map[xTiles][yTiles]==0){//Empty Tile
                    tiles.add(new Tile(X, Y, tileSize, map[xTiles]      [yTiles]));
                X+=tileSize;
                }else if(map[xTiles][yTiles]==2){//Player 
                    tiles.add(new Tile(X, Y, tileSize, map[xTiles][yTiles]));
                X+=tileSize;    
                }
            }
            Y+=tileSize;
            X=0;
            }
        }

    public void drawMap(Canvas canvas){
    for(int index = 0; index < tiles.size(); index++){
        tiles.get(index).drawTile(canvas);
    }
}

}

    class Tile{
    private int type;
    int X;
    int Y;
    int size;
    boolean walkable = true;
    Paint color = new Paint();;
    //rect for the bounds
    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    public Tile(){
        type = 0;
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        size = 0;
        color.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        bounds.set(X, Y, X+size, Y+size);

    }



    public Tile(int X, int Y , int tileSize, int type){
        this.type = type;
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        size = tileSize;
        color.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        bounds.set(X, Y, X+size, Y+size);
    }



    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }



    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }



    public void setX(int x) {
        X = x;
    }



    public void setY(int y) {
        Y = y;
    }



    public int getType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return type;
    }
    public Paint getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color.setColor(color);
    }

    public void drawTile(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(bounds, color);
    }
}
```

**this is my hero class**

```
 class Hero{
    private static final int SIZE = 30;
    //Coordinates 
    int X = 60;
    int Y = 60;
    int sx=30, sy=30;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    public Rect Bounds = new Rect(X,Y,X+30,Y+30);
    boolean solid = true;

    //Map Things
    Map map;

    public Hero(Map map){
        this.map = map;
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        location();
    }




    private void location() {

        for(int index = 0; index<map.tiles.size(); index++){
            if(map.tiles.get(index).getType() == 2){
                this.X = map.tiles.get(index).getX();
                this.Y = map.tiles.get(index).getY();

            }
        }

    }




    public void move(int KeyCode) {
        switch(KeyCode){

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            {if(Collision()){Y+=sy;} break;}
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            {Y-=sy; break;}
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            {X-=sx; break;}
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            {X+=sx; break;}
        }

    }







    private boolean Collision() {
        for(int index = 0; index< map.tiles.size(); index++){
            if(Rect.intersects(map.tiles.get(index).bounds, this.Bounds)){
                return map.tiles.get(index).walkable;}  
        }
        return false;
    }




    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }



    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }



    public void setX(int x) {
        X = x;
    }



    public void setY(int y) {
        Y = y;
    }


    public void position(int x, int y){
        X = x;
        Y = y;

    }

    public void update(){
        Bounds.set(X, Y, (X+SIZE), (Y+SIZE));

    }


    public void Draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(Bounds, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Player", Bounds.left, Bounds.top-5, paint);
    }
}
```

How can i check for collision ?
should i just loop every single tile and then check if the Player's new coordinates will collide ?

this might not be the right way but it worked. i added methods for each move direction Right, Left, Up and Down like this

```
private void moveLeft() {
    for(int index = 0 ; index < map.tiles.size();index++){
        if(yCoord-1 == map.tiles.get(index).yCoord && xCoord == map.tiles.get(index).xCoord){
            if(map.tiles.get(index).walkable){  
            X-=SIZE;
                //My coordinates are flipped for some reason my Xs are Ys and Ys are Xs
                yCoord-=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to record last position of hero, On each move event you can check next tile in direction relative to hero. As you implemented in two dimensional matrix, So if position of hero is say map[0][0] and player got down by one position at time, Then relative Position in  map i.e map[1][0]. this way you cam minimize comparison. Each direction have weight in two dimension  like `up movement can have [CurrentPosition.x-1] [CurrentPosition.y-1], Left can have [CurrentPosition.x] [CurrentPosition.y+1] etc....`

Comment: should i add Xcoord Ycood to my Tile Class then ? so i can recall them from the ArrayList of Tiles

Comment: Since you have definite matrix, you can use simple `array` instead `ArrayList`, But if you want to use `ArrayList` then you can create another `ArraList` say `Arralist< Postion, Tile>` where `Position` is `Xcoord and Ycoord`. I dont know about performace heat in simple `Array` and `ArrayList`

Comment: i finally did it ! it might not be right but it works for now. This is my move method that i created for each direction the player moves

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to checking if your tile is "walkable" then every time your player decides to move the hero (so probably on movement of a joystick or click) you need to determine which tile your hero will be on, and then check that tile to see if it has walkable set to true. Your code is already well on the way to achieving this.

If you're referring to collision with other entities such as NPCs then you will need to get the position of each one of them when the player decides to move the hero and determine if the new position would be the same as the position of one of the collide-able entities.

Something along the lines of:

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN: {
int target = hero.getY() + 1;
if(map.getTile(hero.getX(), target).isWalkable())
   hero.setY(target);
break;
}
```

Comment: thanks to your example i was able to get it working with similar code